# Facing Bazel Build error while using Select() function

Tags: bazel

I have a simple BUILD.bazel for selecting the targets as below. This works, however when i apply the same method to a bigger project having multiple .cpp and .h files, Iam facing an error. Can you please suggest?

Simple BUILD.bazel:

```
cc_library(
    name = "testlib",
    srcs = select ({
          ":pc" :  [ "source/t1.c"  , ],
          ":ecu" :  [ "source/t2.c" , ],
          })
)
config_setting(
    name = "pc",
    define_values = {
                "target" : "pc",
                }
)
config_setting(
    name = "ecu",
    define_values = {
                "target" : "ecu",
                }
)
```

Command that works:
Build for PC:
bazel  build   --define target=pc  //...

Build for ECU:
bazel  build   --define target=ecu  //...

However below error coming when I apply above method to large project:

> failed: configurable "srcs" triggers an implicit .so output even though there are no sources to compile in this configuration caused by.....

Comment: It is happening [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/de7b26acfdfcd9c36ec957305a889ac29f0da30e/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcLibrary.java#L320) seems some source files are missing

Comment: source files are very much present in the mentioned path, I also added a default target to check if it gets selected, but still same error. So it seems Select() is not working as expected.